# On Windows 10 Some FormBorderStyles has no borders

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, formborderstyle

This is only an issue if you have Drop Shadows turned off in appearance settings.

I noticed some of our applications form windows had no borders. Specifically they have been missing the 1 pixel thick border for the left part, right part and bottom part of the form window. All of the forms had in common that they were using FormBorderStyle FixedToolWindow or SizableToolWindow. When it is like this it is hard to distinguish where one dialog stop and another one begins.

We find it plausible that some of our users will have their computers set up like this without the ability to change it.

Is there a way to get the dialog windows looking better without doing anything crazy like manually drawing all borders?

Comment: Mine has borders, Win10, a fresh WinForms project, both for FixedToolWindow and SizableToolWindow.

Comment: that is interesting. I'm going to test on a different machine and check back!

Comment: Our windows 10 test machine is a fresh install of windows 10 with only all critical updates installed. I'll check back later when I have the opportunity to try this on my home computer.

Comment: did you change appearance settings like for example to "adjust for best performance"?

Comment: @dlatikay I tried changing it from "let the computer decide"  to adjust for best look. Or something to that effect, the install is in Swedish =/. I got a drop shadow but I am still missing the left, right and bottom border.

Comment: could not reproduce. screen resolution/dpi/scaling also don't make a difference. assuming .NET 4.0+. do you compile with an older version of the .NET framework? any other non-standard form properties like transparency/zoom/custom non-client area paint code?

Comment: @dlatikay I tried compiling my simple application targeting both .net 2.0 and .net 4.5 and saw the same behaviour both times.

Comment: By design for Win10, the left/bottom/right borders are transparent.  Still quite visible against the large drop-shadow, so visible that is hard to tell that the border is transparent :)  The top border *is* visible, pretty ugly.  Do avoid fighting the machine, you can't win this battle and there's little point in declaring victory when it makes your windows different from other ones used by different apps.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for claryfying. I thought I was going insane for a while! the top border is indeed ugly. I will most likely stop using the ToolWindow FormBorderStyle to make the dialogs look better in low performance scenarios. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting part of a comment by Hans Passant:

> By design for Win10, the left/bottom/right borders are transparent. Still quite visible against the large drop-shadow, so visible that is hard to tell that the border is transparent...

Our application has its own grahpical style that made it especially hard to distinguish where one dialog stops and the other one begins.

The quick solution for us was to stop using FormBorderStyle FixedToolWindow or SizableToolWindow.

Long term we are going trough all our dialogs and the graphical style of our application to make the dialogs more easily distinguishable from each other with or without borders.