# Winform Designer border glitch in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, designer

i have a `PictureBox`in a Form, Dock Property of `PictureBox` is set to Fill.
now to keep only borders of the form, i set `ControlBox` property to false and `FormBorderStyle` to  `SizableToolWindow`.
in Windows 7, it looks like below

[image]

but in Windows 10 same code looks like below
[image]

can anybody explain why this white border appears at top?
 i tried removing padding, margin & Rebuild Solution. none of that helped!
in windows 10 (Visual Studio 2015, Designer) form looks normal (without white top border)
.Net target framework version: v4.6

P.S: Image taken from [here](https://pixabay.com/en/italy-sicily-sea-ocean-reflections-1587278/)

**Update**: here's the Windows Form Designer generated code

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Preview_Image));
    this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // pictureBox1
    // 
    this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
    this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
    this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
    this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
    // 
    // Preview_Image
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
    this.Name = "Preview_Image";
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

Comment: Please check below link  it might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831081/on-windows-10-some-formborderstyles-has-no-borders

Comment: Thanks for your reply Akhilesh, i looked into the link u shared, but its to do with no boarders.. the issue i'm having is extra border..still i tweaked with drop shadow setting in windows, it didn't help..

Comment: Is there any code you might need to share?

Comment: @TaW, i have updated the question with code, have a look.

Comment: OK, nothing special there. I can confirm the result. Looks like the Clientsize is reduced at the top by any sizeable borderstyle..